# After Core 3.0 upgrade, impossible to add-migration with EF Core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

After upgrade core 3.0, it's impossible to add-migration in package manager.
It's my error

```
PM> Add-Migration UpdateAlertTable -Context OozymContext
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ProductInfo' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor..ctor(Object reportHandler, IDictionary args)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.ReflectionOperationExecutor..ctor(String assembly, String startupAssembly, String projectDir, String dataDirectory, String rootNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.ProjectCommandBase.CreateExecutor()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.MigrationsAddCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.CommandBase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Comment: Please always first look at [EF's github page](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/17849) when finding errors in new releases.

Comment: Yes I post already my error https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/18100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a reference of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore version 2.2.6 in a linked project which had the database connection string. I upgraded and it's works

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue after upgrading to version 3.0.  After reading [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/17849#issuecomment-531878807), I installed the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design nuget package and the problem was resolved.

Comment: I have already Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design version 3.0.0 and there is not preview version.

Comment: I put that package into the project where is db connection string and migrations started to work.

Comment: I had the same problem and it went away as soon as I installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design nuget package into the startup project (which had my connection string) and all my problems disappeared!

Answer (score 0):

The commands in the Package Manager console have changed. According to Nuget Gallery reference.
follow below.

```
Add-Migration
Drop-Database
Get-DbContext
Scaffold-DbContext
Script-Migrations
Update-Database
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the rootcause was a linked project with a different EF version in NuGet.